# Today UILabel auto updating

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I have a problem updating a current date label in a 'home' view controller like this:

```
func settingTodayLabel() {

  let todayFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
  todayFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMM YYYY"       
  todayLabel.text = todayFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()) 
}
```

This function is called when 'ApplicationDidBecomeActive', and i expected to update todayLabel text when app is called from background next day but nothing is changed. Old date is displayed. However, if i manualy modify date in settings it works..

```
override func viewDidLoad() {        
super.viewDidLoad()

  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "settingTodayLabel", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: try viewWillAppear instead of  viewDidLoad

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus, this will also not work for the edge case that the view is open when the day changes.

Comment: I think, Al Ex is on the right track, but needs to trigger a custom NSNotification at midnight.

Comment: YYYY might not work as expected also. he needs to use yyyy

Comment: YYYY is wrong, should be yyyy

Comment: Go ahead and include it with your answer

Comment: BTW YYYY would ONLY work because he is always formatting the current date if he uses it with an old date he will be definitely in trouble

Comment: it would yield the wrong date either for the last days of december or first days of January. few years ago the alarm of the iOS clock didn't work for the first few days in December — caused by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` will be fired only if the application becomes active, so you need another notification that fires each day at 0:00 to update the label.

Create a local push notification, that fires at 0:00 and let it broadcast a custom NSNotification that your tune in for like

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "settingTodayLabel", name: "DateChangedNewDay", object: nil)
```

---

AppDelegate

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let notificationType = UIUserNotificationType.None
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)


        var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()

        localNotification.fireDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
        localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay  // for testing: .CalendarUnitMinute
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)


        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("DateChangedNewDay", object: nil)
    }

}
```

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var todayLabel: UILabel!

    deinit{
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "settingTodayLabel", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "settingTodayLabel", name: "DateChangedNewDay", object: nil)

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.settingTodayLabel()
    }

    func settingTodayLabel() {

        let todayFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        todayFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy"  // for testing: "d MMM yyyy HH:mm"
        todayLabel.text = todayFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
    }
}
```

---

I put a sample application online that updates each minute: https://github.com/vikingosegundo/LabelUpdatingEachMinute

---

`"d MMM YYYY"` should most likely be `"d MM yyyy"` as `Y` stands for *Year of "Week of Year"* where the year doesn't start on January 1st, but is switched only between weeks: The first 3 days of January can belong to the last year of the last 3 days of December to the next year. `y` stands for the year as we know it: starts on 1st of January.

Comment: but in the end this will call the same 'settingTodayLabel' 2 times, right?

Comment: not really: it will call it when the app comes to foreground and when a day changes is detected, as it is called for these distinct notifications.

Comment: test it with interval of minutes. I added the codes that would change for that as comments.

Comment: discovered that the label is updating if you let the app in foreground, lock and the next morning unlock the phone.

Comment: and this is not what you want?

Comment: if the app is open in background, not foreground, the label doesn't update. the 'settingTodayLabel()' method however is fired. tested with a println().

Comment: it does here. I tested it. you must have another issue.

Comment: I added yet another `settingTodayLabel()` call. it isn't needed in my simple prototype, but could be needed on your side.

Comment: like you said, i suppose there's another issue cause i used you're code and it's not working.

Comment: did you download my example project? it is working. I cannot fix code I don't know.

Comment: your code works perfectly! i suspect this in my code: @IBOutlet var todayLabel: UILabel! the label is not 'weak'

Comment: a outlet to a view should always be weak, as it it hold strongly by its superview. but I doubt that causes your troubles. You should copy your project, strip it down as much as possible and make it available for review.

Comment: true, it's not the outlet. i'm testing with minutes so not to have to wait until midnight. my 'remove observer' part was in 'viewWillDisappear'. do you think this could be the real problem?

Comment: Sure, as it only will be called when the view containing the label DISappears.